# Добавление и хранение фото

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, подскажите как реализовать возможность добавления фото пользователем в приложение?
И как потом хранить эти фото?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Не очень понятно откуда добавлять планируете, но сохранить можно как в папку приложения так и в галлерею. В папку приложения можно сохранить так:

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File file = new File(directory, "UniqueFileName" + ".jpg");
if (!file.exists()) {
    Log.d("path", file.toString());
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

а если напрямую в галерею то так:

```
private void saveImageToGallery(){
    imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap b = imageview.getDrawingCache();
    Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), b,title, description);
}
```

в этом способе захват картинки идет с виджета. Вот есть туториалы: [1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e14021/capture-image-from-camera-and-selecting-image-from-gallery-o/), [2](https://androidwave.com/capture-image-from-camera-gallery/) и [3](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-write-an-image-file-in-internal-storage-in-android).
[вот есть документация](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java) по работе с картинками

Comment: Я имел ввиду, вот допустим пользователь хочет со своего телефона добавить фотографии допустим в форму отзыва и потом этот отзыв отправить